# I need help understanding a brainfuck code

Tags: brainfuck

```
>, >, <<

convert from ascii

+++++ +++[>----- ->----- -<<-] (a)

multiply

>[>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<-] (b)

separate numbers

>[-]>+> >+++++ +++++<

[

 - >- [>>>]+++++ +++++<<+

 [<<<]>>>>

]

<-

<+++++ +++++>>>[-<<<->>>]<<<
```

I don't understand what this line `- [>>>]` does. My first guess would be that it moves 3 pointers until a pointer with a null value is reached. Except since the pointers have not even been used before, they're all 0 anyway. So the loop shouldn't even have been entered. I'd be really grateful if anyone would help me explain every part of this line:

```
[

 - >- [>>>]+++++ +++++<<+

 [<<<]>>>>

]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's only one pointer in brainfuck. Colloquially we say it's "at" the cell it indicates, and then it moves to another cell to indicate that one, so `>>>` moves the pointer three cells to the right; strictly, `>>>` changes the pointer's value so it indicates the cell three cells to the right of the cell it indicated before.

`-[>>>]` decrements the cell the pointer is at, then moves the pointer right three cells at a time until it reaches a cell holding the value 0.

The earlier parts of this program have already input two characters assumed to be 1-digit numbers, subtracted 48 from them to get the values of those digits, and multiplied them together. Just before the code you mention, the state of the memory array is `0 0 0 1 a 10` where `a` represents the product of the two digits, and the pointer is at the `a`.

So, let's say `a` was 3. Then it will end up doing the outer loop you asked about 3 times. The first time, it decrements `a`, moves pointer to the 10, decrements the 10, then because it's at a 9 (i.e. nonzero), the `[>>>]` moves the pointer 3 cells right, and it sets up another 10 and a 1, so the state of memory will be `0 0 0 1 a=2 9 1 0 10` with the pointer at that second 1 cell. Then the `[<<<]` moves the pointer 3 cells left to the first 1 cell (because the second 1 isn't 0), then another 3 cells left to the leftmost 0 cell (because the first 1 isn't zero either), then stops (because the leftmost 0 cell *is* a zero). Then `>>>>` moves the pointer back to `a` (now 2) and we do the whole loop again.

The next time through this loop, it will decrement a (to become 1), decrement the 9 (to become 8), then the `[>>>]` will move from the 8 to the 10 and then from the 10 three cells right to a 0, and set up another 10, and then scan back to the left again. Then similarly for the third iteration, and after that we end up with:
`0 0 0 1 a=0 7 1 0 10 1 0 10 1 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

Now, notice what happens if `a` was more than 9. The 10th time through, decrementing the cell to the right of `a` produces a 0, which means the `[>>>]` is skipped, which means we set that same cell to 10 again, and increment the 1 that was just left of `a`, producing a 2.
`0 0 0 2 a 10 1 0 10 1 0 10 ...repetitions... 1 0 10 0 0 0 ...`
Then continue. If `a` was greater than 19, then when the cell right of `a` gets zeroed again it gets replaced by a 10 again and that 2 is incremented to become a 3.

The overall result is that after that complex loop has executed `a` times, we end up with:

`0 0 0 x a=0 y 1 0 10 ...repetitions... 1 0 10 0 0 0 ...`
where `x` is 1 more than the tens digit of `a`, and `y` is 10 minus the ones digit of `a`. The whole point of this code was to break `a` down into its two digits. Then the last two lines of this program clean up those digits, so we end up with:
`0 0 o t 0 0 1 0 10 ...repetitions...1 0 10 0 0 0 ...`
where o is the ones digit of a and t is the tens digit of a.

Notice that this code clutters the memory with an amount of `...1 0 10...` proportional to the initial value of `a`.